# jQuery autocomplete submenu (create unordered-list in unordered-list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery autocomplete. On keydown, the selected item isn't "Item1", it would be the full unordered-list including span and the ul.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Items</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Item1</a></li>
      <li><a>Item2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Cars</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Car1</a></li>
      <li><a>Car2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Test</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Test1</a></li>
      <li><a>Test2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is:
On keydown -> menufocus: ui.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item") -> **ui.item** **is undefined** (in jquery.ui.js file)
ul-parameter in menufocus is full list of "Items" `(<ul><li><a>Item1</a></li><li>...</li></ul>).`
What I want: On keydown select Item1, next Item2, next Car1, Car2 and so on...

```
_renderMenu:
$.each( items, function( index, item ) {
...
  if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
      categoryIndex++;

      //Create "li"s for every category and append a span and the new ul to it.
      var myLi = "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'><span class='ui-autocomplete-category-head'><i class='" + category.icon + "'></i> " + category.name + "</span></li>";

      var myLi = $(myLi).removeData("item.autocomplete-item");
      myLi.append("<ul class='ui-autocomplete-inner-ul' role='listbox' aria-labelledby='cat" + categoryIndex  + "' id='innerUlCat"+categoryIndex+"' aria-readonly='true'>");

      var myUl = ul.append(myLi);

        currentCategory = item.category;
  }

  var currentUl = $(ul).find("#innerUlCat"+categoryIndex) || ul;

  li = that._renderItemData( currentUl, item );
});


_renderItemData: return this._renderItemOwn( ul, item );


_renderItemOwn:
  return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
    .append( "<a class='ui-autocomplete-item'>" + item.label + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
```

In _renderItemOwn i added the data "ui-autocomplete-item" but it doesn't work.

Are there any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ui autocomplete combobox with categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039814/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-with-categories)

Comment: Not really but thank you. Do you know another solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem

Comment: Normally the output html for autocomplete is like: <ul>
<ul>
      <li><a>Test1</a></li>
      <li><a>Test2</a></li>
</ul>

If I want to navigate with arrow up and down, i can select "Test1" and "Test2" but in my case when i navigate down to select "Item1" (in my example) jquery thinks that i select the full ul includes:  
<ul>
      <li><a>Item1</a></li>
      <li><a>Item2</a></li>
 </ul> 
and that isn't right.
You know what I mean?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8es0vr2/

Comment: (Just saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503172/jquery-autocomplete-display-two-result-lists) I have the same problem...

Comment: So I think you should mark this as duplicate of the other one (I'll try to think of a solution for you overthere...)

Comment: "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer" Can't flag it as a duplicate!

Comment: good point :) If i'll be able to give a solution I'll update